# How to get size of NFS Export point at client side?

Tags: java, nfs, nfsclient

Can anyone please tell me how to get the size of the NFS Export point at the client side if the export point is available? Is there any command / Java API available for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Lucas' answer here: [How to find how much disk space is left using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051295/how-to-find-how-much-disk-space-is-left-using-java).  If you pass the mount point on the NFS client in to the `getTotalSpace()` and/or `getUsableSpace()` methods on the `File` class, it should return the relevant information for that export.