# tomcat 8 issue while run on the server i got errors like there is not enough space on the disk

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, struts

I got following problem if you have any idea please share with me..

```
Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\catalina.policy: There is not enough space on the disk
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check available disk space before trying to write the file.

See this:
[How to find how much disk space is left using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051295/how-to-find-how-much-disk-space-is-left-using-java)