# Detect no space left on device error

Tags: java

Is there a system indipendent way of detecting when an `IOException` is related to a "no space left on device" error? `IOException` has no methods. Shall I treat it as a generic I/O error without explaining the user why? Or should I simply display the exception message string to the user (which might be too techinical)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java, differently from other languages like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293227/how-to-check-if-ioexception-is-not-enough-disk-space-exception-type), does not keep track of the cause of the `IOException`, but it uses subclasses to better specify the motivation of the exception, for example [`FileNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) is a subclass of `IOException`.

Generally is a good idea to specify the cause for the most common sublcasses, and prefix the error message for `IOException` with a generic description to facilitate the user.

```
try {
   ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (.. other subclasses ..) {
   ...
} catch (IOException e) { // anything else
  System.out.println("I/O Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As part of exception handling, you can check for the available disk space using these methods provided by the [File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace()) class:

```
public long getTotalSpace()
public long getFreeSpace()
public long getUsableSpace()
```

More details can be found in this related question: [How to find how much disk space is left using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051295/how-to-find-how-much-disk-space-is-left-using-java)

Comment: I don't know... it might not be reliable. There are a ton of reasons possible for a no space left error, such as quota exceeded. And on ext2/3/4 file systems you can reserve some blocks for the superuser.